# trying to understand "final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal in Scala

Tags: scala

Coming from Java Land I have been trying to teach myself Scala. Recently I was toying with the `Int` data type and I decided to look up the API for the Int class [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Int).

What perplexed me was the class definition for `Int`, which is `abstract final`.

I am apologetic if I did not read up on the meaning of `abstract` and `final` in Scala before asking this question, but I was curious, so I typed out this post right away.

So what I am trying to understand is:
Are the semantics for `abstract`, `final` and `extends` different in Scala?
Again, it is to the best of my understanding that in Java, one cannot have `abstract` and `final` at the same time.
So how do I interpret `final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal`?

Comment: No, they are not, at least basically (you still cannot instantiate abstract, you cannot inherit/override final). AFAIK, the reason this was done in this way is that some time ago Int and other AnyVal types were just a stubs, rewritten then by the compiler at compile time. They are not since [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/4253124eecba6bed38f1dc961c5c4ee39a29f730)

Comment: Oh, that is useful information. Thanks for pointing out that to me

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As om-nom-nom pointed out in the comment, `abstract` forbids instantiation (`new Int`), whereas `final` forbids subclassing (`new Int { ... }`).

The reason for this is that `scala.Int` is directly represented by the primitive integer type of the Java virtual machine; the other similar types are `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `Boolean`. *Because* they are primitive types on the runtime (exhibiting better performance than so-called boxed types) and the JVM does not allow to add new primitives, there would be no legal way to extend those types. Also there is no way to instantiate them other than by giving a literal (`val i: Int = 33`).

Scala has these types to create a unified object system where there is no logical difference between primitive types and 'objects'. There is however a hierarchical distinction at the top which is `AnyRef` (corresponding to `java.lang.Object`) and `AnyVal` (corresponding to those primitive types; and adding Scala's new type `Unit`).

More on the unified type system is given by the [Tour of Scala: Unified Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128)

Comment: I have to note, that there is also [accepted SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) that will unleash usage of unboxed primitives with non-default behaviour.

Comment: P.S. And although all JVM primitives are represented by subtypes of `AnyVal`, the inverse is not true (`Unit` was already mentioned). In Scala 2.10, it is possible to extend `AnyVal`, creating so-called [Value-Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) which are meant for the implementation of new numeric classes, benefitting from compiler optimisations (e.g. inlining).

Comment: I visited the link @om-nom-nom gave me. It says" The AnyVal types become source files instead of polite compiler fictions. What does that mean? Does that mean that there is not anymore a direct JVM representation for Int, Byte, etc and instead we now have a way to represent them.Sorry if I am not asking an intelligent question.

Comment: Er well, that's a commit message in PaulP prose... If you look at that commit, you'll see that there are actual source code files now for the types, e.g. `Long.scala`—nevertheless, while they define the interface, you can see that none of them have actual method bodies, so IMO the compiler fiction (i.e. encoding as JVM primitives) is still in place. Nothing changed in that respect (from a user perspective).